# Is $f(x+a) - f(a) = f(x) + f'(a) x$ an identity?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, analytic-geometry

Given a differentiable function of $x$, denoted by $f(x)$; is $f(x+a) - f(a) = f(x) + f'(a) x$ an identity?

For example, if $f(x)=x^2$, then it gives $(x+a)^2 - a^2 = x^2 + 2ax$, which is true.

So, if this identity is true, the derivative appears from a change of coordinate system (or translation)?

Comment: Taking the derivative or your equation gives $f'(x+a) = f'(x) + f'(a)$, so $f'(x)$ must be additive.  Thus, assuming $f'$ is nice, it must be of the form $f'(x) = 2c x$ for some constant $c$.  This implies $f(x) = cx^2 + d$ for some constants $c$ and $d$.   (Probably the fact that $f'$ is a derivative already guarantees it's nice enough.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is not true, take as an example the function $f(x)=c$, where $c\neq 0$ is a constant.

Comment: Or $\sin(x)$, or $\cos(x)$ .